# How to set NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit and others NotebookApp settings in JupyterHub?

Tags: python, configuration, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I want to start my notebooks with `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000000` arguments. Where one could set it in JupyterHub?

Answer (score 29):

Open the command line and enter

`jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1e10`

This should start jupyter with the increased data rate.

Comment: Is there any way to set it within a running notebook, i.e. without having to restart jupyter?

Answer (score 11):

You have to create config file using this command `$ jupyter notebook --generate-config`, The answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-when-viewing-image-in-jupyter-notebook/43420383#43420383)

Answer (score 10):

04: "IOPUB data rate exceeded" problem of "jupyter low memory.." 
in windows:

> 1. open cmd:
> 2. in main path:C:\Users\siege> (this is my root path)
>
>    type the command: "jupyter notebook --generate-config"
>
>    the you hav: C:\Users\siege>jupyter notebook --generate-config
> 3. system will generate "jupyter_notebook_config.py" in 
>          path:C:\Users\siege>.jupyter
> 4. open "jupyter_notebook_config.py"   find the line
>
>    ## #c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 1000000
>
>    uncomment it and change it to:
>
>    ## c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 100000000
> 5. save it
> 6. restart jupyter

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_YlLf6fa5A

Comment: this is the only correct answer since it works with `jupyterhub` (not just `jupyter notebook/lab`) as per the OP

Answer (score 2):

to enable it with jupyter-lab, use the following cmd for your environment

```
conda activate 'your env'
jupyter-lab --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1e10
```