# How to convert list of array having two elements?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have input like this:

```
y=[[array([ 0.12984648,  0.02116148,  0.08041889, ..., -0.11139846,
       -0.0893152 , -0.05336994]), 1], [array([-0.11865588, -0.16726171, -0.06753636, ...,  0.00991138,
       -0.11180532, -0.01146698]), 0] ]
```

I want to convert it into:

```
y=[
[[ 0.12984648,  0.02116148,  0.08041889, ..., -0.11139846,
       -0.0893152 , -0.05336994], 1], [[-0.11865588, -0.16726171, -0.06753636, ...,  0.00991138,
       -0.11180532, -0.01146698], 0]
]
```

Comment: The question is how did you create this? Does each element of y have the same dimension? If so convert it to a numpy array then convert it to list. If Not, you will have to loop through each element to convert everything to a list. Last option will be to use itthe way it is since you can do almost the same thing to the array as to the list

Comment: Thats waht you want - we solve problems you have - so what problem do you have doing what must be done? [mre]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have non-rectangular arrays. So your only option is to use lists and here is how you convert it to lists:

```
y = [[i[0].tolist(),i[1]] for i in y]
```

output:

```
[[[0.12984648, 0.02116148, 0.08041889, ..., -0.11139846, -0.0893152, -0.05336994], 1], 
 [[-0.11865588, -0.16726171, -0.06753636, ..., 0.00991138, -0.11180532, -0.01146698], 0]]
```

Comment: I am getting this output: IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs

Comment: I am using google colabs and this is happens when I am trying to print y

Comment: @harshinisewani that is a different issue. You can create a separate question for it. Nonetheless, as error message says, you probably have to set `NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit` value to a higher limit than 1MB/s. That is not the issue with the code above.

Comment: how can I set that value?

Comment: @harshinisewani Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490495/how-to-set-notebookapp-iopub-data-rate-limit-and-others-notebookapp-settings-in answer your question?