# How to iterate over pairs: a group and its next group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, iteration

I have a grouped dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0, 1, 1, 2], 'b': range(5)})
g = df.groupby('a')
```

```py
for key, gr in g:
    print(gr, '\n')

   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  1

   a  b
2  1  2
3  1  3

   a  b
4  2  4
```

I want to do a computation that needs each group **and** its next one *(except the last group, of course)*.

So with this example I want to get two pairs:

```py
# First pair:
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  1

   a  b
2  1  2
3  1  3


# Second pair:
   a  b
2  1  2
3  1  3

   a  b
4  2  4
```

##### My attempt

If the groups were in a list instead, this would be easy:

```py
for x, x_next in zip(lst[], lst[1:]):
    ...
```

But unfortunately, selecting a slice doesn't work with a `pd.DataFrameGroupBy` object:

```py
g[1:]       # TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'. (It thinks I want to access the column by its name.)
g.iloc[1:]  # AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44479213/14627505)
is related but it doesn't answer my question.

*I am posting an answer myself, but maybe there are better or more efficient solutions (maybe pandas-native?)*.

Comment: Can you provide expected output on the shared dummy data?

Comment: The computation part, really, is irrelevant to this question. I am only interested in getting the pairs of groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a `pd.DataFrameGroupBy` to a list that contains all groups (in tuples: grouping value and a group),
and then iterate over this list:

```py
lst = list(g)
for current, next_one in zip(lst[], lst[1:]):
    ...
```

Alternatively, create an iterator, and skip its first value:

```py
it = iter(g)
next(it)
for current, next_one in zip(g, it):
    ...
```

A more complicated way:

`g.groups` returns a dictionary where keys are the unique values of your grouping column, and values are
the groups. Then you can try to [iterate over a dictionary](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/), but I think it would be unnecessarily complicated.