# Jupyter Notebook error message that IOPub data rate exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I get the following error message when I try to import a .txt file with the following code,

```
with open("cobuy.txt", "r+") as my_file:
    for item in my_file:
        my_file.write("%s\n" % item)

text = open("obuy.txt").read()

text
```

:

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
```

From googling around, it seems there is a problem with Jupyter Notebook version 5.0. It shows that you can put the following code in the terminal to resolve that: jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000000, I can't seem to get this to work: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2287

Are there any other solutions to this?

Comment: any help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOPub data rate exceeded when viewing image in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-when-viewing-image-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44679222/8235224) is working for me.

Start the notebook as below:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10
```

Comment: how do I do this if I access my jupyter notebook through the Anaconda screen rather then the terminal? Thanks!