# IOPub data rate exceeded - in Jupyter Notebook - Anaconda 5 - Windows

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am getting the error message:

```
Warning message:
"package 'bindrcpp' was built under R version 3.4.2"IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
```

Having done some research I followed the advice given in this post: [IOPub data rate exceeded when viewing image in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-when-viewing-image-in-jupyter-notebook)

More specifically, I created a jupyter_notebook_config.py file and then commented out the line c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 1000000 and change it to a higher default rate.  See below:

[image]

[image]

Nevertheless, the same error appears.

Your advice will be appreciated.