# IOPub data rate exceeded error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I was trying to make cufflinks offline, but it is showing an error in the Jupyter Notebook. Jupyter was able to execute every cell except the last line of code (`cf.go_offline()`).

Can anyone fix it? For the first time, I am trying out this cufflinks library. Is there any issue with the version of the package, or is it any other issue?

Input:

```
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
```

Output:

```
warning message-
IOPub data rate exceeded.The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit
```

[image: output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have to descibe exactly what you attempted (i.e. in a way that another person can reproduce what you have done). Else noone will be able to help you because they have no hint on what might have caused your situation. See also [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @freginold thanx for the help

Comment: You might have a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420383/3082472), where the display of a large image caused this error. Note the "update" section of that answer; Check first if the default value of the mentioned config option is also low for you.

Comment: Thanx @akraf ..

Comment: You can write an answer to your question yourself if you have solved the problem. Then other persons researching on the same problem can find a solution more easily!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOPub data rate exceeded when viewing image in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-when-viewing-image-in-jupyter-notebook)