# The function doen't iterate over the whole array

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following code which gets two arrays and finds the location of each item in the second array based on the first array. For example, for 23 from `loc1`, which is between 20 and 25 in array it should return 20.

```
matrix_x = []
def binarySearch(alist, loc):
    for item in loc:
        midpoint = len(alist)//2
        if midpoint == 1:
            if item<alist[midpoint]:
                return matrix_x.append(alist[midpoint-1])
            else:
                return matrix_x.append(alist[midpoint])         
        else:
            if item<alist[midpoint]:
                return binarySearch(alist[:midpoint],loc)
            else:
                return binarySearch(alist[midpoint:],loc)
    return matrix_x

array = [5,10,15,20,25]
loc1= [23,7,11]

print(binarySearch(array, loc1))
print(matrix_x)
```

I expect to receive this array as the result:

```
[20,5,10]
```

But I receive only the first item like this:

```
[20]
```

Comment: remove the `return` keyword by using the return statement you end the script  execution.

Comment: Your algorithm is questionable as it combined two very different features into a single function; my recommendation is to decouple the two, first being the recursive `binarySearch` into its own thing that takes the list and __one__ location, the other being the iteration through the list of locations and passing that to the decoupled `binarySearch` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html):

```
import bisect

def binarySearch(alist, loc):
    return [alist[bisect.bisect(alist, i) - 1] for i in loc]

array = [5,10,15,20,25]
loc1= [23,7,11]
print(binarySearch(array, loc1))
```

Output:

```
[20, 5, 10]
```

Finding the index is simpler:

```
def binarySearchIndex(alist, loc):
    return [bisect.bisect(alist, i) - 1 for i in loc]
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Your solution is the best! Do you know how can we get the index of each item instead of the item itself? For example, in this question, it should give me [4, 0, 1].

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you have the privilege to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). ;)

Comment: Thanks. I receive this error: IOPub data rate exceeded.

Comment: My actual dataset is really huge. It has more than 5000 records. Does this function work for such a big dataset too?

Comment: This is problem with [Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-when-viewing-image-in-jupyter-notebook).

Comment: 5000 should be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning the `matrix_x.append` statement, so it only ever appends 1 item, in this case `20`. To get the behavior you want, you may need to restructure your function some.