# Dynamic plots in holoviews

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh, holoviews

I want to create a dynamic plot using holoviewS of amount given and balance remaining. Ideally a line or bar chart and I can select based on category

The data(df) is as below

```
ID Amount_Given Balance Interest  Date_issues   category Amount_Given_Band
   1   200         0       15       20180102       A          0-200
   2   700        500      25       20180203       B          500-1000
   3   1500       705.50   45       20170603       A          1001-5000
   4   20000      20000    200      20171231       C          10000-20000
```

Below is the code

```
%%opts Curve [width=600 height=400 show_grid=True ] (color='indianred', alpha=0.5, line_width=1)
ds = hv.Dataset(df).sort(['Date_issues'])
ds.to(hv.Curve, 'Date_issues' ,'Amount_Given_Band', 'category')
```

but i get the error

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
```

i am using bokeh extension

Comment: You need to increase the `iopub_data_rate_limit` config variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-when-viewing-image-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: @HYRY i have updated to 100,000,000 but i still get the error `IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit``.