# IOPub data rate exceeded in Jupyter notebook (Version 5.4.0)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am running into an issue where when I read a txt file, the following message is generated :

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

I tried to follow the instructions provided in this Stack Overflow post here:
[IOPub data rate exceeded when viewing image in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-when-viewing-image-in-jupyter-notebook)

However, I can't get past the first step of generating a config file via the Command Line. When I try to call Jupyter Notebook in the command line as a part of step 1, the command line doesn't recommend it. I tried calling Jupyter Notebook from within the file directory in which it sits. I confirmed it is the right directory by verifying the last modified date.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10
```