# How do I change --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit for .jupyter?

Tags: python, windows-10, jupyter-notebook

This is my first time on stackoverflow, in general, I am quite new to programming at all. 
I tried to create a list out of a csv-file resulting in:

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

I guess I already found the solution to my actual problem here...

[IOPub data rate exceeded when viewing image in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-when-viewing-image-in-jupyter-notebook)

... however I do not know how to change the settings of my jupiter notebook to change the data_rate_limit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change the limit, type the following into the command line :

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000
```

Then the notebook opened will have the new limit.

Answer (score 8):

In your config file `jupyter_notebook_config.py`

if you uncomment and edit the line:

`c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 1000000`

This will change the data rate limit.

If you don't have that file, you can generate it using:
`jupyter notebook --generate-config`
and it will be located somewhere like `~/.jupyter/`

This config file will also let you set values such as `msg_rate_limit` (which limits messages to iopub) and `rate_limit_window` (which will change how quickly it checks for the rate limits), among many other useful notebook configurations...

Answer (score 3):

Saw this somewhere else and this helped.

Open your jupyter notebook using this command:

```
`jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10`
```