# Error message : IOPub data rate exceeded. When extracting string from a list

Tags: python, regex, text, nlp

good day,

I am writing a function to pre-process string data. I wish to lower case the string data. I attempted to test the function by passing in a list called messages which is a list of strings. However, I keep getting this error when I call the function:

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

This is my function here:

```
def text_preprocess(message)
""" message: the text data to be processed """

words = ''.join(str(twit.lower()) for twit in message)

return words 

# Testing the function on a list of strings called messages

test = text_preprocess(messages)

# Length of the list messages
print(len(messages))
Output: 1548000
```

I am confused as to why that message occurs? Any suggestions here would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How large is the list?

Comment: @KlausD.I updated the code check last bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOPub data rate exceeded in Jupyter notebook (when viewing image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-in-jupyter-notebook-when-viewing-image)

Comment: what if I want the function to pass in any data structure and convert it to a string? @KlausD.