# Can't read txt file because of IOpub data rate exceeded

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have written a small code to open, read, close and print a txt file. I run it using `Jupyter` notebook, but the file is not printed and I got a message saying that IOpub data rate exceeded.

I have generated a default config file and increased the value from `1000000` to `10000000` but there is no change in execution printout.
Below the code and the message, do you know for which reason and what can I do to overcome this issue?

> IOPub data rate exceeded. The notebook server will temporarily stop
>   sending output to the client in order to avoid crashing it. To change
>   this limit, set the config variable
>   --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit.

Current values:

```
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

I have generated default config file, and increased the value from `1000000` to `10000000` but there is no change in execution printout.

```
import os
# open Output_log.txt for reading text
myfile = open("E:\\science\\Projet situation\\Output_log.txt", "rt") 
# read the entire file into a string
contents = myfile.read()
# close the file
myfile.close()
# print contents
print(contents)
```

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-in-jupyter-notebook-when-viewing-image

Comment: Yes, and I modifed the value un the dafault configuration file as suggested, in line: #c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 10000000 (adding one 0), but this didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10 in anaconda to start the notebook and it is working fine now, the file is being read.
But it seems that I need to execute this comand every time I need to open the notebook, is it normal?