# How to set NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit in sagemaker

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker

I got the error when i running the jupyter notebook in sagemaker:

```
OPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

I tried several solutions (e.g., [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-in-jupyter-notebook-when-viewing-image), [solution2](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/239)), but it did not work.

Could someone know how to solve the issue?

Comment: Take the answer below and add `c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 10000000` to the end of  `.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` file. If you just uncomment and add a zero it doesn't work, at least that was my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can uncomment and edit this line `c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 1000000` in `./.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` in Sagemaker terminal.

I used vim editor to do that.

Comment: Do we need to restart the sagemaker notebook instance after this? Or the kernel?