# File handling code in Python is not giving any output

Tags: python

I am working with deep learning project in JUPYTER NOTEBOOK

```
# Loading a text file into memory
def load_doc(filename):
    # Opening the file as read only
    file = open("C:\\Users\Project\Flickr8k.token.txt", "r")
    text = file.read()
    file.close()
    return text
```

By using function I need to load a File and display a File Contents 
but not getting any output.

Comment: Are you calling your function and printing the output anywhere? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Note that `load_doc` doesn't even use the `filename` parameter at the moment.

Comment: Iam not able to understand this functions concept
def load_doc(filename)

Comment: I have a linked to the official tutorial in my answer: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call `load_doc()`, Also as you have you path in function no need for `filename`
.check this

```
def load_doc():
    # Opening the file as read only
    file = open("C:\\Users\Project\Flickr8k.token.txt, "r")
    text = file.read()
    file.close()
    return text

print(load_doc())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help .i got the output

Comment: @SrikanthBhattu Great, if the answer help you and it was useful, then accept the answer and vote up :)

Answer (score 2):

Right now, it looks like you are not calling your `load_doc` function anywhere, hence the lack of output. You also don't use the `filename` parameter in your function. I recommend you seek out a tutorial to learn about how to use functions in python - see the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

As an aside, you should look to use the context manager approach to opening a file, since this ensures that the file handle is closed, even if an exception occurs while the file is open.

```
def load_doc(filename):
    # Opening the file as read only
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        return fh.read()

# Call the function with my file path
content = load_doc("C:\\Users\Project\Flickr8k.token.txt")
# Print the output
print(content)
```

Comment: ok 
but iam Getting This Error----

IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of `jupyter`. You may also increase the `iopub_data_rate_limit` yourself using `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10`. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-in-jupyter-notebook-when-viewing-image)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier here to use "with open()" as it handles all the tricky stuff with the files automatically. It also needs to be a raw string to escape the \ otherwise python gets confused thinking you're putting in a control character 
`with open(r"C:\Users\lewis\example\example.txt", 'r') as file:
    data = f2.read()
    print(data)`

after the indentation the file is automatically closed