# How to solve "IOPub data rate exceeded." in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I tried to find subsets of 2,3,4 from a unique value set of **58** unique entries in the Jupyter notebook. Below is the function which I used.

```
import itertools 
def findsubsets(s, n): 
    return [set(i) for i in itertools.combinations(s, n)]
```

```
print(findsubsets(x,2))
print(findsubsets(x,3))
print(findsubsets(x,4))
```

It worked fine for subsets of 2 and 3. But when it is executed for the subsets of 4, it gave the following message.

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOPub data rate exceeded in Jupyter notebook (when viewing image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-in-jupyter-notebook-when-viewing-image)

Comment: this problem is similar to the problem discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-in-jupyter-notebook-when-viewing-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Jupyter Notebook using the following command.

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10
```

Then try to run your query.