# IOPub data rate exceeded in my Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I tried all the possible solutions I found in a stack overflow.
Tried solution from here: [IOPub data rate exceeded in Jupyter notebook (when viewing image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288550/iopub-data-rate-exceeded-in-jupyter-notebook-when-viewing-image)

But, I get an error message: Access is denied, please correct me If I am doing it at the wrong place [image]

```
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the values directly in the config file?